# How to apply an Arithmetic operation on each Group of elements with the same ID in the list

Tags: java, java-stream, bigdecimal, collectors

I have **class** `Data10` which have 4 fields.

And I have a list of `Data10` objects.

I want to do an **arithmetic operation** with **values** of the elements with the *same* **ID**. As a final result I need to generate new `Data10` object with same **ID**, same `year`, new `name`(`"D"`), and `value` (based on **arithmetic operation**).

```
public class Data10 {
    int id;
    int year;
    String name;
    BigDecimal value;
}
```

```
List<Data10> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new Data10(1, 2020, "A", new BigDecimal(5.5)));
list.add(new Data10(1, 2020, "B", new BigDecimal(2.5)));
list.add(new Data10(1, 2020, "C", new BigDecimal(8.5)));

list.add(new Data10(2, 2020, "A", new BigDecimal(1.5)));
list.add(new Data10(2, 2020, "B", new BigDecimal(6.5)));
list.add(new Data10(2, 2020, "C", new BigDecimal(2.5)));
                              
list.add(new Data10(3, 2020, "A", new BigDecimal(6.5)));
list.add(new Data10(3, 2020, "B", new BigDecimal(1.5)));
list.add(new Data10(3, 2020, "C", new BigDecimal(9.5)));

list.add(new Data10(4, 2020, "A", new BigDecimal(3.5)));
list.add(new Data10(4, 2020, "B", new BigDecimal(7.5)));
list.add(new Data10(4, 2020, "C", new BigDecimal(5.5)));
```

I want to apply the below **formula** for each group of **ID**:

> ****D** = **A** - (**B** * **C**)** [Airthmetic operation for group of objects with the same **ID**]

I applied filter for object names (`"A|B|C"`) so that only element with these names can appear in the list. And there will be only one  unique object for each name and Id.

I've tried grouping the list based on **ID** but don't know how to apply the formula in each group.

```
list.stream().filter(data10 -> data10.getName().matches("A|B|C"))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data10::getId));
```

**Expected:**

```
Data10(1, 2020, "D", -15.75);  [ Formula (D= 5.5 - (2.5 * 8.5)) ]
Data10(2, 2020, "D", -14.75);  [ Formula (D= 1.5 - (6.5 * 2.5)) ]
Data10(3, 2020, "D", -7.75);   [ Formula (D= 6.5 - (1.5 * 9.5)) ]
Data10(4, 2020, "D", -37.75);  [ Formula (D= 3.5 - (7.5 * 5.5)) ]
```

Comment: For each **ID** there will be exactly one object with name `"A"`, one with `"B"` and one with `"C"`, or there could be multiple objects with such names? Assume that at least one of them is always present

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko In the list we have multiple object like name of "A", "B" and "C" but I applied filter in the list based on this three name ("A", "B" and "C") so after apply filtered the final list I have only name of "A", "B" and "C" for each group of Ids.

Comment: I mean, is it possible that there will be more then **one** "A" object with the same **id**?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko No, For same Id have unique object for each name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group these objects first by `id` and then by `name` with `Collectors.groupingBy` which will produce a nested map. And then reduce this intermediate map into list by producing a new data-object for each value in the map.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Data10> data10List = // initializing the list

    List<Data10> result =
            data10List.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data10::getId, // by id
                                Collectors.groupingBy(Data10::getName))) // by name
                    .values().stream()
                    .map(map -> processValues(map))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    result.forEach(System.out::println); // printing the result
}
```

For the method below, I've made an assumption that all combinations **`id`** and **`name`**  are unique. Therefore, every list in the map will contain only one element (*Note: hard-coded **names** as well as hard-coded **math logic**, normally has to be avoided*).

```
public static Data10 processValues(Map<String, List<Data10>> map) {
    BigDecimal combinedValue =
            map.get("A").get(0).getValue() // "A"
                    .subtract(map.get("B").get(0).getValue() // "B"
                            .multiply(map.get("C").get(0).getValue())); // "C"

    return new Data10(map.get("A").get(0).getId(),
                      map.get("A").get(0).getYear(),
                      "D",
                      combinedValue);
}
```

To avoid hard-coding the logic for the math operation, you can define a custom **functional interface** (there's no build-in function in the JDK that expects three argument). And make the method `processValues()` more generalized by adding this interface and expected names as parameters to the declaration. So that it'll be possible to apply different math logic without need to change the method.

An interface and implementation might look like that:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface TripleFunction<A, B, C, R> {
    R calculate(A a, B b, C c);
}
```

```
TripleFunction<BigDecimal, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, BigDecimal> mathOperation =
          (a, b, c) -> a.subtract(b.multiply(c));
```

These are the changes required to utilize this function (in the stream pipeline and inside the `processValues`):

```
.map(map -> processValues(map, mathOperation, "A", "B", "C"))
```

```
public static Data10 processValues(Map<String, List<Data10>> map,
                                   TripleFunction<BigDecimal, BigDecimal, BigDecimal, BigDecimal> mathOperation,
                                   String a, String b, String c) {

    BigDecimal combinedValue = mathOperation
            .calculate(map.get(a).get(0).getValue(),
                       map.get(b).get(0).getValue(),
                       map.get(c).get(0).getValue());

    return new Data10(map.get("A").get(0).getId(),
            map.get("A").get(0).getYear(),
            "D",
            combinedValue);
}
```

**Output** (*data listed in the question, was used as an input*)

```
Data10{id=1, year=2020, name='D', value=-15.75}
Data10{id=2, year=2020, name='D', value=-14.75}
Data10{id=3, year=2020, name='D', value=-7.75}
Data10{id=4, year=2020, name='D', value=-37.75}
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed hard coded name should be avoided.

Comment: @RishiKumar You are welcome. I have an idea on how to make it more flexible. I'll add it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Wow!! I have become a fan of yours by thinking about your code style and way of thinking. ;)

Comment: BigDecimal combinedValue = mathOperation
            .calculate(map.get(a).get(0).getValue(),
                       map.get(b).get(0).getValue(),
                       map.get(c).get(0).getValue());  How to resolve a,b,c, I am getting error while put inside the method.

Comment: @RishiKumar I've added the whole method and a change that has to be done in the stream pipeline. If works with my dummy data objects, the output is the same. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

group the list by id, then loop through each group and get the a, b, and c values,
the add new Data to list with D name with Formula value.

```
   list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data10::getId))
                .entrySet().forEach(e -> {
                    var a = e.getValue().stream().filter(d -> d.getName().equals("A")).findFirst().get().getValue();

                    var b = e.getValue().stream().filter(d -> d.getName().equals("B")).findFirst().get().getValue();

                    var c = e.getValue().stream().filter(d -> d.getName().equals("C")).findFirst().get().getValue();

                    var formula = new BigDecimal(a.subtract(b.multiply(c)).doubleValue());
                    list.add(new Data10(e.getKey(), 2020, "D", formula));
                });
```